# getJSON to update javascript datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an api which is called using ajax (getJSON).  Currently it works perfectly if I want to append to a defined div, namely 'open'.

However, what I really want to do is update the static values in my javascript for the datetime picker, specifically the minTime and maxTime.

My code is as below:

AJAX

```
$.getJSON("{{ url('api/openingtimes')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 
    function(data) {
        if (data.success != false ) { 
            $('#open').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('#open').append('<div>' + value.weekday_start_time +' ' + value.weekday_end_time +'</div>');
            });
        }
});
```

JAVASCRIPT datetimepicker

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
    if( currentDateTime.getDay()==6 ){  
        this.setOptions({
            minTime:'10:00',
            maxTime:'21:00'
        });
    } else
        this.setOptions({
            minTime:'08:00',
            maxTime:'22:00'
        });
    };

    jQuery('#start_date_time').datetimepicker({
        onChangeDateTime:logic,
        onShow:logic
    });               
});
```

API (JSON)

```
{
    "weekday_start_time": "08:00",
    "weekday_end_time": "22:00",
    "weekend_start_time": "10:00",
    "weekend_end_time": "21:00"
}
```

I'm struggling to see how this can work via my JSON feed.  If anyone can advise, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your JSON is a little weird as it should probably have quotation marks around the times. Is that just a typing mistake?

Comment: Perhaps there should be quotations marks around the times.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. Just do it like this:

```
$.getJSON("{{ url('api/openingtimes')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
    if (data.success != false ) { 
        jQuery('#start_date_time').datetimepicker({
            minTime: value.weekday_start_time,
            maxTime: value.weekday_end_time
        });
    }
});
```

When you call the datetimepicker again using an object as the parameter, it knows you want to set the options.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using this plugin, as there are several out there with the same name: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Thank you for input, however I'm unsure how this appends it to datetimepicker function. I tried your code but nothing happened.